# Adding a hyperlink which referece a file of folder inside our file server is not working on firefox and Chrome

Tags: publishing-page, html, hyperlink, enterprise-wiki

I am working on an enterprise wiki site collection. and i want to add hyperlinks to folder and files which are inside our file server. 
So i edit a wiki page >> under Insert tab >> Link >> from address. and i add the following link :-

```
file://fielservername/deps/HR
```

now when i click on the link using IE the related folder open well inside my PC. but on chrome and Firefox when i click on the link nothing will open/happen.... so can anyone adivce what is the problem ?

Comment: These network paths are being supported by only IE. Even if you directly type these paths in the Chrome, Firefox browsers it won`t work.

Comment: @VenkatKonjeti so it is not related to sharepoint ,, but rather to how Firefox and chrome handles url that references files and folders ?

Comment: Yes. If you have a mapped drive in your local machine then it works for Chrome and Firefox also. Example I have a mapped drive to (M) and I can access folders using `file:///M:/Advertising/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to work these network drives in all browsers you have do following steps.

1. Add a network mapping to all machine on the same Drive Name.
2. Then use the following syntax to open files in the folder

   `Example: file:///M:/Advertising/`

In this case all my organization computers mapped to "M" drive

Comment: sill using this link `file:///t:/deps/HR/` will only work on IE.. in our case we have a mapped drive name `t`

Comment: In my above example, M is a network drive which is mapped to my department folder and `Advertising` is a folder on a network drive (M). In your case also `deps` should be a folder in a T drive. Can you confirm? Mine is working. For testing type the above address on the IE browser.

Comment: yes my path `file:///t:/depts/HR/` is valid since it will open correctly in i am using IE, while it will not work if i uses chrome or firefox... so yes depts is a folder and HR is a sub-folder

Comment: mine is working in all browsers.